# Установка расширений Google Chrome прямо на сайте. Как это сделать?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

На сайте должна быть возможность демонстрации экрана, для этого необходимо получить на это разрешение, делается это путем обращения к установленному расширению google chrome.

Так вот, как можно установить это расширение в браузер пользователей у кого его нет прямо на сайте, видел такое на других сайтах, сначало появляется окно с запросом на установку расширения затем оно устанавливается, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [Inline Installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation), если вкратце, то необходимо добавить `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="..." />` со ссылкой на приложение и вызвать метод `chrome.webstore.install()`, и еще установка приложения с сайта должна быть разрешена в Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Спасибо, сколько искал ничего не нашёл.